# How to run a method from a UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uialertview

I want to have this method  `[User logOut];` run when a user touches the **Log Me out** button in the following `UIAlertView`.

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Logged in!" message:@"Logged in to App!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:@"Log me out", nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
```

how would I go about doing that? The "Okay" works for the cancel button. I just need the other button/method to work.

thanks for any help

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like;

```
- (void)AlertConfirm
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
    [alert setTitle:@"Confirm"];
    [alert setMessage:@"Log out?"];
    [alert setDelegate:self];
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Yes"];
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"No"];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

And

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        // Yes, do something
    }
    else if (buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        // No
    }
}
```

Good luck,
Nathan

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the UIAlertView delegate method:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

Make sure you set yourself as the delegate of your alertView.

Answer (score 1):

Set the alert view's delegate to be self, and in your .h add

The following delegate method will be called when a button is pressed:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

Then you can see what button was pressed by doing something like:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if ((alertView == alert) && (buttonIndex == 0))
        NSLog(@"alert's \"Okay\" button was pressed");
    else 
        NSLog(@"alert's \"Log Out" button was pressed");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set your view controller to be the `delegate` of the `UIAlertView`:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Logged in!" message:@"Logged in to App!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:@"Log me out", nil];
        alert.delegate = self;
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
```

Then handle in the delegate callback:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex 
{
    if (buttonIndex == alertView.cancelButtonIndex) {
        // Cancelled
        return;
    }

    // Log them out
}
```

Note the test `(buttonIndex == alertView.cancelButtonIndex)`. This is better form than checking an absolute value for the button index.